# Good book for application of PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book that covers the gaps in my book. It should cover following problems.

1. Equation of Vibrating string(1-d)
2. Heat Equation (1-D or 2-D)
3. Laplace Equation

Can you refer me a book that cover solutions to aforementioned PDEs with clarity?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following references:

$1.~~$ "Elementary Applied Partial Differential Equations With Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems" by Richard Haberman

$2.~~$ "Elements of Partial Differential Equations" by Ian N. Sneddon

$3.~~$ "Partial Differential Equations" by Victor Ivrii

$4.~~$ "Partial Differential Equations" by Ioannis P Stavroulakis & Stepan A Tersian